# True or false:if $A\subset B$, then $P(A)<P(B)$?

Tags: probability

They ask me if this statement is true or false, and explain why. They suggest I write an example showing why it is false or true.

> The statement is: if $A\subset B$, then $P(A)<P(B)$.

What I tried was to draw a Venn diagram and show that and show that $pa(A)=p(B)$, so then the answer is false. But I want to know if there is a better way to show this, or something a little bit more formal (not too much).
Thanks.

Comment: Well with strict inequality it's false.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B=A\cup (B-A)\,\,\,,\,\,A\cap (B-A)=\varnothing\quad,P(B-A)\ge 0$$
$$P(B)=P(A)+P(B-A)\implies P(A)\le P(B)$$

Comment: That was fast. Thanks a lot :D.

Answer (score 3):

False: In a normal distribution, $P(\Bbb R)=P(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})=1$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is false.
A hint for the reason could be:
if $B=A\cup C$ and $C\neq\varnothing$ and $P(C)=0$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing$
 Then everything should work.

Comment: Use `\varnothing` or `\emptyset` to show the empty set, not `\phi`.